# How to run gradle task after another task, even the last task has dependecies which are failed

Tags: android, gradle

The problem is:

1. There is an android application. I want to execute android instrumentation tests (The gradle task is **connectedCheck**).
2. I want to open generated report in browser independently of whether were tests successfull or not.

Here the code of my task:

```
task showReportInBrowser << {
    String resultsPath = projectDir.toString().replaceAll("\\\\", '/')
    resultsPath = resultsPath + '/build/reports/androidTests/connected/index.html'
    java.awt.Desktop.desktop.browse resultsPath.toURI()
}
```

I have tried this:

```
connectedCheck.finalizedBy showReportInBrowser
```

If the **connectedCheck** executes normally I get what I want.
But if the **connectedCheck** fail, my **showReportInBrowser** doesn't execute.

I think this is because the **connectedCheck** task depends on the **connectedDebugAndroidTest** task, which is failed while execution, therefore the **connectedCheck** even doesn't start, and my **showReportInBrowser** does't start too.

So I tried this:

```
connectedDebugAndroidTest.finalizedBy showReportInBrowser
```

But gradle said: *Error:(75, 0) Could not find property 'connectedDebugAndroidTest' on project ':app'.
Open File*

I don't understant: why the **connectedCheck** and **connectedDebugAndroidTest** are shown both in gradle *verification* group, but I can use in my buildscript only **connectedCheck**?

How can I reach my goal?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In my case the fail was in `connectedDebugAndroidTest` task. So, to ignore all fails in particular subtask just use something similar:

```
connectedDebugAndroidTest {
    ignoreFailures = true
}
```

But in this case it causes

> Error:(66, 0) Gradle DSL method not found: 'connectedDebugAndroidTest()'

As shown [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36343828/6077215) you can use the following bypass:

```
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    connectedDebugAndroidTest {
        ignoreFailures = true
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide more generic way in case you change your build types / flavors names and/or add more of them

```
project.gradle.taskGraph.whenReady {
    -> project.tasks.findAll { it.name =~ /connected.+AndroidTest/ }.each {
        it.ignoreFailures = true
    }
}
```

With this it doesn't matter what are you testing, no FAIL status will be given for any instrumentation test