# Why can't I use gradle task connectedDebugAndroidTest in my build script?

Tags: android, gradle, android-gradle-plugin

I can refer to **connectedCheck** task (which came from android plugin) from my build script:

```
connectedCheck.finalizedBy AndroidShowTestResults
```

But trying to use **connectedDebugAndroidTest** (which came from android plugin too)

```
connectedDebugAndroidTest.finalizedBy AndroidShowTestResults
```

gives me

> Error:(48, 0) Could not find property 'connectedDebugAndroidTest' on project ':app'.

And if I try

```
task connectedDebugAndroidTest << {print '123'}
```

it curses me with

> Error:Cannot add task ':app:connectedDebugAndroidTest' as a task with that name already exists.

I don't undestand why I cannot refer to **connectedDebugAndroidTest**?

Available gradle tasks are shown below:

[image: Gradle tasks]

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The android plugin defers the addition of several tasks especially those that have buildType or flavor names in them till a very late stage of the configuration phase. Which in turn means if you try to refer to these yet-to-be-added-tasks by name, you're likely to see a "does not exist" type error messages. If you want to add dependencies around deferred-created tasks, you should wait until configuration is complete:

```
gradle.projectsEvaluated {
    connectedDebugAndroidTest.finalizedBy AndroidShowTestResults
}
```

Alternatively, you can add a listener to task-graph events, so you can do stuff as soon as a certain task is added to task-graph:

```
tasks.whenTaskAdded { task ->
    if (task.name == 'connectedDebugAndroidTest') {
        task.finalizedBy AndroidShowTestResults
    }
}
```

Comment: I apologize I wasn't able to give you the bounty - my acc was suspended. Thanks for the explaining answer. First code snippet doesn't work, but secont does.

Answer (score 0):

Try

```
task connectedTest(dependsOn: ["connectedDebugAndroidTest"]){

}
connectedTest.finalizedBy "AndroidShowTestResults"
```

Answer (score -1):

I think you should try to open test and rebuild.

[image]

Comment: I even don't have this checkbox. Android Studio 1.5.1.